# Whenever i try run my python code with pygame the window opens and then stops responding after a second or any input

Tags: python, pygame

heres all the code i have currently, it is just a start of a pacman game i am creating all that should be shown is a tab with press space to play
ive looked at previous responses to similar questions and i have what i should need to make it work but it still doesn't... i hope someone can help, thanks.

```
import os
import sys
import pygame



Start_window_font = 'arial black'


pygame.init()
vector=pygame.math.Vector2


class RPMGame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((450, 600))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.running = True
        self.state = 'startwindow'
        self.load()
        self.node_width = 450//25
        self.node_height = 600//30
def run(self):
    while self.running:
        if self.state == 'startwindow':
            self.startwindow_events()
            self.startwindow_update()
            self.startwindow_draw()
        if self.state == 'gaming':
            self.gaming_events()
            self.gaming_update()
            self.gaming_draw()
        #fps
        self.clock.tick(60)
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def draw_text(self, words, screen, position, size, colour, font_name, centered = False):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(font_name, size)
    text = font.render(words, False, colour)
    text_size = text.get_size()
    #centering the starting text##
    if centered: 
        position[0] = position[0]-text_size[0]//2
        position[1] = position[1]-text_size[1]//2
    screen.blit(text, position)

def load(self):
    self.gameboard = pygame.image.load('pacmanmaze.png')
    self.gameboard = pygame.transform.scale(self.gameboard, (450, 600))

def draw_maze(self):
    for x in range(450//self.node_width):
        pygame.draw.line(self.screen, 107,107,107, (x*self.node_height, 0), (x*self.node_width, 600))


def startwindow_events(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.running = False
        ###key used to start game##
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self.state= 'gaming'

def startwindow_update(self):
    pass

def startwindow_draw(self):
    ####colour of background##
    self.screen.fill(0,0,0)
    ##start game text (text, position, text size, colour, centering)##
    self.draw_text('CLICK TO START GAME', self.screen, (225,300), 16,(255,0,0), 
    Start_window_font, centered= True)
    self.draw_text('HIGH SCORE', self.screen, [5,0] ,(225,300), 16,(255,255,255), 
    Start_window_font)
    pygame.display.update()


def gaming_events(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.running = False
        

def gaming_update(self):
    pass

def gaming_draw(self):
    self.screen.blit(self.gameboard, (0,0))
    self.draw_maze()
    pygame.display.update()



game = RPMGame()
game.run()
```

**edit
i realised that i forgot to change the variable for one of my states which was needed for the stop part

Comment: the initial state is `'begin'`, but you are not checking for that state anywhere so it will skip all of the `if` statements in the main loop and just call the clock tick... forever (until the program is forcibly stopped)

Comment: The indentation in the shown code is incorrect. Every function after the constructor is not part of the class. Also, I highly doubt you'll need 60fps for a basic pacman game

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of minor issues.  When the app started and then immediately stopped, did you not notice that you're getting syntax and runtime errors on the console?

In this line:

```
self.screen.fill(0,0,0)
```

`fill` accepts one parameter, which is an RGB tuple:

```
self.screen.fill((0,0,0))
```

You have the same problem in `draw_maze`:

```
        pygame.draw.line(self.screen, 107,107,107, (x*self.node_height, 0), (x*self.node_width, 600))
... should be ...
        pygame.draw.line(self.screen, (107,107,107), (x*self.node_height, 0), (x*self.node_width, 600))
```

Then, in this call:

```
    self.draw_text('HIGH SCORE', self.screen, [5,0] ,(225,300), 16,(255,255,255),
```

I don't know what the [5,0] was trying to do, but `draw_text` isn't expecting that parameter.  Just remove it.

Then, in this code:

```
    if centered: 
        position[0] = position[0]-text_size[0]//2
        position[1] = position[1]-text_size[1]//2
    screen.blit(text, position)
```

you pass in `position` as a tuple.  You can't modify a tuple.  You need to build a new tuple, or just change to a list:

```
        pos = list(position)
        if centered:
            pos[0] = pos[0]-text_size[0]//2
            pos[1] = pos[1]-text_size[1]//2
        screen.blit(text, pos)
```

With that, your app at least starts for me.